# Image not being displayed in divison

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a division in my HTML page and I am trying to display an image in it.
I had done something like this :

In java-script part :

```
var nameoffile="andrew.png";
$("#detected").show().html('<img src="trainingImages/""'+nameoffile+'" >');
```

In HTML part :

```
<div  id="detected"></div>
```

Please help me in finding the issue with my code. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need concatenate your value properly as well as setting the `html` first then show the content:

```
$("#detected").show().html('<img src="trainingImages/'+nameoffile+'" >');
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntax error. It should be:

```
$("#detected").show().html('<img src="trainingImages/'+nameoffile+'" >');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var nameoffile="andrew.png";
$("#detected").show().html('<img src="trainingImages/'+nameoffile+'" >');
//                                  remove "" here  ^^
```